# How to add root CA of self-signed certificate to the actions-runner-controller

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, k3s, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

Maybe somebody knows in what way it's possible to add a root CA to the [actions-runner-controller](https://github.com/actions/actions-runner-controller) ?

It's worth mentioning that I'm interested in the actions-runner-controller image, not the actions-runner image.

Logs of actions-runner-controller pod:

```
ERROR    runner    Failed to get new registration token    {"runner": "github-actions-runner-small-001-rw88q-nhmhq", "error": "failed to create registration token: Post "https://test-github.example.com/api/v3/orgs/myexample/actions/runners/registration-token/": could not refresh installation id 5's token: could not get access_tokens from GitHub API for installation ID 5: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"}
github.com/actions/actions-runner-controller/controllers/actions%2esummerwind%2enet.(*RunnerReconciler).updateR
```

It's running on K3S cluster.

Thanks in advance,

Dockerfile:

```
FROM summerwind/actions-runner-controller

ADD ./My_Root_CA.pem /usr/local/share/my-root-ca.pem
```

Expecting:

Controller should trust a self-signed certificate of my GitHub Enterprise Server

Comment: apparently related: https://github.com/actions/actions-runner-controller/discussions/957

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Create a configMap with certificate in .pem:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> create configmap <configMap-name> --from-file=my-root-ca.pem
```

2. Attach configMap to the deployment like in example:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: actions-runner-controller
        image: someimage:v1
        volumeMounts:
        - name: <configMap-name>
          mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/my-root-ca.pem
          subPath: my-root-ca.pem
          readOnly: false
      volumes:
      - name: <configMap-name>
        configMap:
          name: <configMap-name>
```